# How to replace text with regex?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How would I write regex in Visual Studio's Find and Replace to change all instances of the following text:

> If (whatever control and overloads) = "" then

To this:

> String.IfNullorEmpty(whatever control and overloads) then

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are the above strings or code?

Comment: @ThomasKilian I understand it to mean using the Find-and-Replace dialog in Visual Studio.

Comment: Ah. That makes the question clear. I can't answer since I don't have VS, but likely someone else can help. Usually a regex looks like `If \((.*)\) = "" then` and the replacement `String.IfNullorEmpty(\1) then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for:

> If (.*) \= "" Then

And Replace with:

> String.IfNullOrEmpty($1) Then

Although, what I think you actually meant was:

> If String.IsNullOrEmpty($1) Then

The trick is in simply surrounding the desired part of the pattern in parenthesis to make it a RegEx group.  Then in the replace string you can reference the groups with the $ syntax.